# why do I get null when unmarshalling?

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

I am trying to read a XML file using JAXB, I'm also placing these into a list.

data code:

```
package xmll;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;


@XmlRootElement(name="data")
public class data {

    private int millis;
    private String stamp;
    private String datetime;
    private int light;
    private double temp;
    private double vcc;


    @XmlElement
    public int getMillis() {
        return millis;
    }
    public void setMillis(int millis) {
        this.millis = millis;
    }

    @XmlElement
    public String getStamp() {
        return stamp;
    }
    public void setStamp(String stamp) {
        this.stamp = stamp;
    }

    @XmlElement
    public String getDatetime() {
        return datetime;
    }
    public void setDatetime(String datetime) {
        this.datetime = datetime;
    }

    @XmlElement
    public int getLight() {
        return light;
    }
    public void setLight(int light) {
        this.light = light;
    }

    @XmlElement
    public double getTemp() {
        return temp;
    }
    public void setTemp(double temp) {
        this.temp = temp;
    }

    @XmlElement
    public double getVcc() {
        return vcc;
    }
    public void setVcc(double vcc) {
        this.vcc = vcc;
    }

    public data(int millis, String stamp, String datetime, int light, double temp, double vcc){
        super();
        this.millis = millis;
        this.stamp = stamp;
        this.datetime = datetime;
        this.light = light;
        this.temp = temp;
        this.vcc = vcc;
    }
    public data(){
        super();
    }
```

datalist code:

```
public class DataList {

    private List<data> listData = new ArrayList<data>();


    @XmlElement(name="Data")
    public List<data> getDataList(){
        return listData;
    }
    public void setListData(List<data> listData) {
        this.listData = listData;
    }
}
```

Main code:

```
public class jaxb {
    public static void main(String[] args)throws JAXBException, FileNotFoundException {

        try {
            JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(DataList.class);
            Unmarshaller ums = jc.createUnmarshaller();
            DataList dl = (DataList)ums.unmarshal(new File(".\\data\fridgelogdata.xml"));

            System.out.println("the data bitch");
            for (data d: dl.getDataList()){
                System.out.println("millis=" + d.getMillis());
                System.out.println("stamp=" + d.getStamp());
                System.out.println("datetime=" + d.getDatetime());
                System.out.println("light=" + d.getLight());
                System.out.println("temp=" + d.getTemp());
                System.out.println("vcc=" + d.getVcc());    
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

Does the problem lie within the actual xml file I'm using?
Thankful for any help :)

Here is the first row of xml, the xml file is quite large and includes thousand of rows so I cant display the whole file. Apologies for any beginner mistakes.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <root>
     <row>
               <millis>1000</millis>
               <stamp> 1273010254</stamp>
               <datetime> 2010/5/4 21:57:34</datetime>
               <light> 333</light>
               <temp> 78.32</temp>
               <vcc> 3.54</vcc>
               </row>
```

Comment: Please show the xml (or xsd) ...,edit the post to included it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your xml is **completely** different to the annotations in your data and datalist code.

Considering xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
  <row>
     <millis>1000</millis>
     <stamp>1273010254</stamp>
     <datetime>2010/5/4 21:57:34</datetime>
     <light>333</light>
     <temp>78.32</temp>
     <vcc>3.54</vcc>
   </row>
</root>
```

An correctly annotation class could be:

**Root.java**

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "", propOrder = {
   "row"
})
@XmlRootElement(name = "root")
public class Root {

  @XmlElement(required = false)
  protected List<Row> row;

  public List<Row> getRow() {
    if (row == null) {
        row = new ArrayList<Row>();
    }
    return this.row;
  }

  @XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
  @XmlType(name = "", propOrder = {
    "millis",
    "stamp",
    "datetime",
    "light",
    "temp",
    "vcc"
  })
  public static class Row {
    protected Integer millis;
    protected String stamp;
    protected String datetime;
    protected Integer light;
    protected double temp;
    protected double vcc;

    public Integer getMillis() {
        return millis;
    }
    public void setMillis(Integer value) {
        this.millis = value;
    }
    public String getStamp() {
        return stamp;
    }
    public void setStamp(String value) {
        this.stamp = value;
    }
    //-...continue with the other getters and setters

  }
}
```

EDIT Add method to unmarshall as asked in comment

```
JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(Root.class);
Unmarshaller ums = jc.createUnmarshaller();
Root root = (Root)ums.unmarshal(new File("pathToYourFile"));
for (Root.Row r: root.getRow()){
  System.out.println("millis=" + r.getMillis());
  //ecc...
}
```

Comment: Cheers for the answer mate, i have made changes to my main but they are not right, got myself a little confused. How would i change my previous main to work with root.java ?

Comment: I have added it to the answer.... have fun.... (tested it with your example add close tag of root, and it works ; ).....

Comment: Consider accepting the the answer (the green check under the voting next to the answer) to close this question